# Server not receiving notifications from custom menu item

Tags: google-mirror-api

I have created a Google Mirror API subscription that pings a file a server (which logs all input to a text file) when a custom menu item is selected.  The trouble is, the file on the server is not pinged and the log file is not updated.

The app is written in PHP and can be accessed below:
http://www.gpop-server.com/glass-notifications/

I have included both my subscription object and menu object below for reference:

```
Google_SubscriptionsListResponse Object
        (
            [__itemsType:protected] => Google_Subscription
            [__itemsDataType:protected] => array
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Google_Subscription Object
                        (
                            [callbackUrl] => https://gpop-server.com/glass-notifications/post.php
                            [collection] => timeline
                            [id] => timeline
                            [kind] => mirror#subscription
                            [__notificationType:protected] => Google_Notification
                            [__notificationDataType:protected] => 
                            [notification] => 
                            [operation] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => UPDATE
                                    [1] => INSERT
                                )

                            [updated] => 2014-04-27T16:29:28.309Z
                            [userToken] => 113161576523948071568
                            [verifyToken] => 535d306816bdb
                        )

                )

            [kind] => mirror#subscriptionsList
        )


Google_MenuItem Object
(
    [action] => CUSTOM
    [id] => notify
    [payload] => custom
    [removeWhenSelected] => 
    [__valuesType:protected] => Google_MenuValue
    [__valuesDataType:protected] => array
    [values] => Array
        (
            [0] => Google_MenuValue Object
                (
                    [displayName] => Notify Server
                    [iconUrl] => 
                    [state] => 
                )

        )

)
```

I've had something similar to this working perfectly a few weeks ago, so I am hoping it is not something that was inadvertently caused by a Glass firmware update.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Offhand these look good, although there are a few things I'd suggest checking:

1. The subscription result looks correct, although you didn't indicate how you got it. Was this the subscription returned from adding it or from doing a `subscriptions.list` command? You might want to do the latter to make sure it is still registered with the Glass servers.
2. Try making some manual calls to the URL in question, making sure you're using a POST operation (and not a GET, which is what a browser might test). Something like   `curl --data "" https://gpop-server.com/glass-notifications/post.php` should do it.
3. It does look like your server has a valid non-self-signed SSL certificate, so that part seems ok.
4. The MenuValue object doesn't seem to have a state set, while I would have expected a state of 'DEFAULT'. I don't see how this would be it, but it does stand out as an issue.

Comment: Thank you Prisoner!  I was able to add the DEFAULT state to the MenuValue and did some testing using CURL and was able to ping the server successfully.



However, the issue still persists when using Google Glass (XE 16.2).  I think it may be a firmware bug as the notification is able to ping the server fine when using the Mirror API Playground (https://developers.google.com/glass/tools-downloads/playground).  I have reached out to Google directly regarding this issue so hopefully that will shed some light.